# is using an intent to show the map cost money?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

Sorry if the question is so basic I am new to android and programming.
I am going to make an app, in this app I need to show locations or maybe even directions in map lots of time. It is very likely, an interested user see the map more than 20 times in a row in just one time lunching the app.
I choose to use google map api for this application, but I saw in their website you have to pay money if your app use map more than 25000 a day and it is likely to happen if I have more than 2000 active users easily, but I am not sure I can make money with this app or not; so I have 2 choose and I am not sure about one of them:

1- using intent to show geo on an external app like google map but does it cost that money or not? (thats my main question)

2- using another api like http://www.openstreetmap.org/ or http://leafletjs.com/

Which option do you recommend? And if that's the option 2, which api do you recommend and why?

Note that the program work base on website and its data base and that website gonna have same functionality as the app and it need to use that api, site gonna use drupal-8 probably but not 100 percent sure yet.

I googled for the answer but I didnt get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if you do an explicit intent to maps this way https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents you have nothing to pay, it's an intent not an API call, in fact you don't need api key to do that.

2) I've used openstreetmap in the past, it's not difficult, but maybe it depends on your skill.

If you are really new, I suggest you to use intent. You can always switch to openstreetmap when you become more confident!

If you want to see an example with openstreetmap in my github I have a project fell free to look at the code if this helps you https://github.com/doJester13/Indoor-GPS

Comment: tnx for your time :), the first part answered my question, i thought maybe they record which app had the request for the map in intent so maybe they charge the fee in your developer account this way. but what about the website? if i request the map (in a mini window?) from their site so users can see the map on their site they can record my ip and dont let my useres to use map anymore to make me purchase the key am i right?

Comment: with "request the map in a mini window" you mean using a webview? in this case you have to use an apikey for google maps (yes you have to purchase if you do many requestes) and in the webview you load a page with your custom map.

Comment: no, not webview. the android part is ok. i wrote in my question i have to build a website with same functionality which the app use its database to bring that functionality to android. so i use intent in app but what should i do in website? can i use geo to make a url which led user to google map site? so i dont have to bring the map to my own site? because some of my users may use a desktop or any other devise, so they might have to use website not the app

Comment: You had to use the same DB for your web application and android application, both apps have to load/ save in this DB.
You can save (lat, lng) of every marker you have on the map, and replace all markers when you reload the map.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, your users can do 150 000 Google Places requests per day, if you Enable Billing with your credit card on Google (That doesn't cost, just verifies your identify). The Maps API is completely free

By the time you have so many users that they use all the map requests, you can probably afford it.

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details

Comment: tnx for your time :)